I want to dynamically create a network and attach the same network to the docker-compose services
This is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: "3.7"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ${NETWORK_NAME}
      
services:
  runner:
    container_name: runner-${PROJECT_NAME}
    build:
      context: .
      target: production
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /host/path/to/files:/app/files
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - cache
    ports:
      - "${DYNAMIC_PORT}:8000"
    networks:
      - "${NETWORK_NAME}"
    environment:
      - FILE_BASE_PATH=/app/files
      - TERM=xterm
    command: node dist/index.js

  queue_worker:
    container_name: queue_worker-${PROJECT_NAME}
    build:
      context: .
      target: production
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /host/path/to/files:/app/files
    depends_on:
      - cache
    networks:
      - "${NETWORK_NAME}"
    command: node dist/Service.QueueWorker/index.js

  cache:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
    networks:
      - "${NETWORK_NAME}"
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning
    volumes:
      - "${CACHE_VOLUME_NAME}:/data"

This is my bash script:
#!/bin/bash

find_free_port() {
  local port
  while true; do
    port=$(shuf -i 2000-65000 -n 1)
    if ! nc -z localhost $port; then
      echo $port
      return 0
    fi
  done
}

APP_PORT=$(find_free_port)
REDIS_PORT=$(find_free_port)

# timestamp-based unique project names
PROJECT_NAME="project_$(date +%s)"
NETWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}_network"
CACHE_VOLUME_NAME="cache_${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Create a custom network
docker network create -d bridge "$NETWORK_NAME"

echo "Application is running on port: $APP_PORT under project: $PROJECT_NAME"

REDIS_PORT=$REDIS_PORT \
DYNAMIC_PORT=$APP_PORT \
PROJECT_NAME=$PROJECT_NAME \
NETWORK_NAME=$NETWORK_NAME \
CACHE_VOLUME_NAME=$CACHE_VOLUME_NAME \
docker-compose -p "$PROJECT_NAME" -f docker-compose.instance.yml up

# docker network rm "$NETWORK_NAME"

When i run docker-compose up, I get this error:

service "cache" refers to undefined network project_1728932200_network: invalid compose project

I'm trying to dynamically create docker-compose containers and also adding custom network for every collection of containers. And I want the network names to be dynamic and the services to get attached to their respective network.

Compose actually pretty much has this capability on its own, but you need to let it choose the names of things.  Compose has the notion of a project name; each distinct project name has its own set of containers, volumes, and networks, and the project name is embedded in the names of things Compose generates.  Your script already has a docker-compose -p option so you're using this capability; you need to stop overriding various names.
In the Compose file, delete all of the networks: blocks; Compose will generate a network Compose-named default (and Docker-named something like default_projectname) and attach all of the containers to it automatically.  Delete all of the container_name: lines.  You didn't include the top-level volumes: block, but delete the name: lines there too.
The one other part of this is the port assignments.  Again, Docker has the ability to automatically pick a host port when it's publishing a port.  In the ports: block, list a single port that only indicates the container-side port.
With some additional cleanup, the Compose file should look like
version: "3.7"

volumes:
  cache:

services:
  runner:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /host/path/to/files:/app/files
    depends_on:
      - cache
    ports:
      - "8000"
    environment:
      - FILE_BASE_PATH=/app/files
      - TERM=xterm

  queue_worker:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /host/path/to/files:/app/files
    depends_on:
      - cache
    command: node dist/Service.QueueWorker/index.js

  cache:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379"
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning
    volumes:
      - "cache:/data"

To get the Docker-chosen port number back out, you'd need to run docker-compose port.
This also significantly simplifies your wrapper script.  You just need to choose the project name, start Compose, and print out the port numbers.  You can reduce it to
#!/bin/sh
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME="project_$(date +%s)"
export COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.instance.yml
docker-compose up -d
echo "app port:"
docker-compose port app
echo "cache port:"
docker-compose port cache
docker-compose wait app
docker-compose down -v

